# How to map rotation of 180 degree multiples to scale from +1 to -1?

Tags: animation, drivers

I have an object that continually rotates on the y-axis. I want to scale it, so that it periodically gets scaled down to -1 and then back up to +1. So at 0° the scale should be 1, at 180° -1, at 360° 1 again and continuing that over 360°.

I tried using a driver, but didn't get anywhere.
First I convert the total rotation into the amount over the next lower full multiple of 360 using this function:

```
((x * 180 / pi) / 180) % 1
```

It converts radians to degrees, than divides by 180 to find out how many multiples of 180 is inside of x and reduces the result modulo 1. This linearlly maps 0° to 0 and 180° to 1.
Now, I moved it down using -0.5 and multiplied it by 2 to get 180° back up to 1, to get this function:

```
((((x * 180 / pi) / 180) % 1)-0.5)*2
```

Graphing this function looks like this:
[image: Graph of the function "((((x * 180 / pi) / 180) % 1)-0.5)*2"]

The Problem here is the jarring jump from 1 to -1.

Ideally, I need a function that looks roughly like the green graph in the picture below, however it doesn't need to be linear, the important thing is that 0° matches -1 and 180° 1 etc. as exact as possible to prevent small shifts turning into big shifts at values like 30,000°+:
[image: Graph of the function "((((x * 180 / pi) / 180) % 1)-0.5)*2" and hand drawn graph]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not using a cosine function?

Otherwise try the triangle wave function described here on Wikpedia:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_wave

Comment: I tried sine before, but that didn't work out. Cosine makes more sense, I didn't think of that before. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked. You're welcome :)